# javascript- how to determine number of times a html construct has occurred as a sibling prior to the currently selected construct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have obtained the currently selected content in a web page, using Javascript.

For example sample HTML for a web page is given below--

```
    <div id="divText">Text 1
        <div id="divText1_1">Text 1_1</div>
        <div id="divText1_2">Text 1_2</div>
    </div>
```

Now, the user has selected text "Text 1_2" - from the HTML above, we can see that this is the second div within the div named "divText"- how do I get this information using Js code? The info that I want- "divText1_2" is the second div within its parent HTML element. ( I want to know the number of divs that occurred before "divText1_2"- when text within "divText1_2" has been selected by the user)...

Answer (score 0):

If the info you want is just the text in that div, then try:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    alert($("#divText1_2").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont know the div id when the user selects some text from the browser, then u can find the html element using jquery e.g, :

```
dom = $('*:contains("Text 1_2")');
```

create an array of dom like :

```
dom_array = []
for( var j=0; j<dom.length; j++){
  dom_array[j] = dom[j];
}
```

now the last element in array will be the exact html element which contains the selected text.(assuming selected text will occur only once)

```
selected_id = dom_array[dom_array.length-1].id // 

var a = document.getElementById("divText");
    var arr = [];
    var div = document.getElementById("selected_id"); 
    for( var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      arr[i] = a[i];
    }
    console.log(arr.indexOf(div));
```

Comment: I wont know the id of the div beforehand-- the user will select some text in a web page-- if this is within a div (for example) then I want to find out how many divs are there before this div, as siblings of the selected div...